# need help creating permalinks in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, url-mapping

So I am trying to create a unique permalink each time that a person posts on my webpage and I want it to be relatively search engine friendly so I have made  a little code to change the title to a good search engine title and it is working but then my handler cannot accept it.  At least that is what I think is happening because the webpage just gives me a 404 error.  The HTML works fine because when I redirect to a static page it all goes through.  Here is the applicable code:

```
def post(self):
    subject = self.request.get('subject')
    content = self.request.get('content')

    if subject and content:
        p = Post(parent = blog_key(), subject = subject, content = content)
        p.put()

        id=str(p.key().id())

        subject = str(subject)
        subject = subject.replace(' ', '25fdsa67ggggsd5')
        subject = ''.join(e for e in subject if e.isalnum())
        subject = subject.replace('25fdsa67ggggsd5', '-')
        subject = subject.lower()

        url = '/blog/%s/%s' % (id, subject)
        self.redirect('/blog/%s/%s' % (id, subject))

class PostPage(BlogHandler):
    def get(self, post_id):
       key = db.Key.from_path('PersonalPost', int(post_id), parent=blog_key())
       post = db.get(key)

       if not post:
          self.error(404)
          return

       self.render("permalink.html", post = post)

class PersonalPost(db.Model):
    subject = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    content = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
    last_modified = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now = True)
    user_id = db.StringProperty(required = True)

    def render(self):
        self._render_text = self.content.replace('\n', '<br>')
        return render_str("post.html", p = self)

def blog_key(name = 'default'):
    return db.Key.from_path('blogs', name)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/blog/([0-9]+)/([.*]+)', PostPage)]
```

And again it works when I just have it redirect to the main page and list them but not when I try to direct to the new SEO page.

UPDATE:

The test url I am using is setting

```
subject = "test-url"
id = "1234"
```

The app then directs me to www.url.com/blog/1234/test-url but it gives me a 404 error.

Comment: Is this your actual indentation? You appear to be trying to define the `PostPage` class within a `post` function that never gets called...

Comment: the indentation was disrupted when I pasted it, I just fixed it though. the indents are all correct on the actual code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define two groups in `('/blog/([0-9]+)/([.*]+)` but your PostPage.get() only takes one.
Change it to def `get(self, post_id, subject)` or remove the second group `('/blog/([0-9]+)/[.*]+`

Comment: still no luck with that... still getting a 404.  how should the handler syntax be? is ('/blog/([0-9]+)/([.*]+) good?

Comment: @clifgray Please provide samples of the test urls you are using

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at the quotes on ur handler mapping, it seems inconsistent.

- yours: `app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/blog/([0-9]+)/([.*]+)', PostPage)]`
- try : `app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(['/blog/([0-9]+)/([.*]+)', PostPage)]`